# How to keep the styling of html retrieved from a server?

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am working with the Gmail API and am retrieving the emails as HTML. I want to display the emails on my site but the styling of the emails is getting messed up due to me using the materiazlizecss frame work for other parts of my site.

When I remove the materializecss css file from the page, and just load the emails in a simple div, the styling is left intact, but gets messed up when I add it in. What is the best solution to this? Is there a way to ignore the css file for certain sections of the html?

Comment: You can ignore CSS by loading the email in an iframe.  However, there are several drawbacks to using iframes.  Hopefully someone will suggest a better answer.

Comment: Maybe through the Shadow DOM, but it's not widely supported. The easy path is with an iframe

Comment: I ended up using iframes to load the emails. Just curious though, what are the draw backs of this?

Comment: iframe doesnt have drawbacks as such. but the main  issue I see is if you dont manage the height and width of the iframe properly.

Comment: Wow. That's exactly the issue I'm having. The height of the iframe is messing up and is much smaller than the email, making it display the scroll bar. Is there a way to make the height cover the content? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try using iframe for your mail content?

You could also try using different CSS class for mail content.

Comment: So maybe put the email in a div with a certain class like 'email' and then reset all the styling in that class so that it can be overridden by the email's styling?

Comment: Yes. But, I would recommend using iframe for such things. That way you can completely separate out things from your site.